# xpath - select based on a lookup?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've currently got the following XML:

```
<root> 
  <entry a="1/2/a.txt"/>
  <entry a="1/2/b.txt"/>
  <entry a="1/2/c.txt"/>
  <entry a="1/2/d.txt"/>
  <err b="2/b.txt"/>
  <err b="2/c.txt"/>
  <err b="2/y.txt"/>
  <err b="2/z.txt"/>
</root>
```

Using XSLT 1.0, I'd like to select all "entry"s, where @a contains any "err/@b". Is this possible?

e.g. Expected Result:

```
  <entry a="1/2/b.txt"/>
  <entry a="1/2/c.txt"/>
```

To give you an idea, I'm playing with the following xslt (but it's obviously not working). Thanks in advance!

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//entry[count(//err[contains(@a,@b])>0]"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//entry">
   <xsl:if test="//err[contains(current()/@a, @b)]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the solution. Just before I accept it, is there anyway in XSLT1.0 that I can store the results in an xsl:variable?
e.g.
    <xsl:variable name="results">
      <xsl:for-each select="//entry">
     <xsl:if test="//err[contains(current()/@a, @b)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
or
<xsl:variable name="results" select="some xpath?" />

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer a more push-style solution, like so ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="error-files" match ="err" use="@b" />

<xsl:template match="entry[key('error-files',substring-after(@a,'/'))]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use keys, you could use ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="entry[@a[substring-after(.,'/') = ../../err/@b]]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And in response to the OP's comment, Yes, there is no problem storing the results in a variable. For example, you could do ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="error-files" match ="err" use="@b" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="results">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$results" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry[key('error-files',substring-after(@a,'/'))]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```